# Emacs ruby-mode: (not so) strange indentation for new Rails code conventions

Tags: ruby, emacs, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This "bug" may be lurking since the beginning of `ruby-mode`, but I noticed it recently when I met new Rails standards. For, instance, if I'm about to construct a simple helper a-la Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial:

```
def logo(name = nil)
  l = image_tag(path, alt: 'Sample App', class: 'round')
                # indentation moves cursor here
```

as you can see, indentation is messed up and it does not follow 2-spaces conventions like it used to. Note that if I change these to "regular" hash conventions it works like a charm.

```
def logo(name = nil)
  l = image_tag(path, :alt => 'Sample App', :class => 'round')
  # indentation is now here
```

This is really frustrating in MuMaMo buffers, since I can get nicely nested HTML code. My cursor ends up in column 2342 at the end of the page. I thought it was Rinari / nXHTML issue, but nope. I'm writing this helper in plain `ruby-mode` and I get the same behaviour.

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of ruby-mode are you using?  If it's from the Ruby repository directly, you should probably file a bug.  I think the new hash syntax is only since 1.9, so it's entirely possible that ruby-mode.el hasn't kept up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems fixed in ruby [HEAD](https://raw.github.com/ruby/ruby/trunk/misc/ruby-mode.el)